# Warning everytime i try to use DeepSort

Tags: python, numpy, deep-learning, pytorch, image-segmentation

i'm using Mask R-CNN to segment cells in frames of videos, then the segmented cells are tracked by DeepSort. The tracker is actually working, the problem is that sometimes it's not able to track some cells and this warning shows up:

```
WARNING: Failed to extract image patch: [0, 415, 4, 1] 
WARNING: Failed to extract image patch: [0, 415, 3, 1] 
WARNING: Failed to extract image patch: [0, 415, 5, 1]
WARNING: Failed to extract image patch: [0, 415, 6, 1]
WARNING: Failed to extract image patch: [1160, 415, 3, 1]
WARNING: Failed to extract image patch: [1160, 415, 5, 1]
WARNING: Failed to extract image patch: [1160, 415, 4, 1]
WARNING: Failed to extract image patch: [696, 624, 6, 1]
```

I'm sure that i'm passing the bboxes' coordinates in the correct way [xmin, ymin, width, height]
Consider that the values are so low because they are cells. Does anyone know why the tracker is not able to track these cells?

Comment: so you're saying a 1-pixel-tall patch is useful? or that image patches a mere handful of pixels wide contain anything visually trackable?

Comment: I just want to understand why the tracker is returning me this, since there is nothing wrong, i'm not saying it's useful.

Comment: I'm saying those widths and heights are pointless, and the tracker seems to take issue with them as well, so I guess we have to agree to disagree. good luck!